# multiple web hooks with Unbounce

Tags: html, forms, twilio, webhooks, zapier

What is the term for a webhook that makes another set of webhooks?

A recent kludge (Unbounce, Zapier, Twilio) only allows me one webhook (i.e. custom one from Zapier)

https://zapier.com/zapbook/twilio/unbounce/

Eventually, however, I will need to generate multiple actions on different (customzed) platforms, so I was hoping to have a hook that goes to one place and then from there, vector off hooks to my other beta site (including Zapier).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note your question was about unbounce, but included Zapier.  I'm assuming from this that you were looking to use Zapier as the "one place" (i.e in the middle)"

Now I don't know Zapier, but came across your question looking along the same lines. The terms I'm familiar with on this are "one-to-many", "fan-out" or "publish/subscribe" communication styles - but aware that these may be a bit old school in Web 2.0 world.

In my search I came across a Zapier Support post [on Multiple Zaps](https://zapier.com/support/questions/1595/use-the-zapier-delayed-trigger-to-trigger-multiple-zaps-from-one-webhook/).

In summary, looks like you may be able to achive this using a ["Zapier Delay Trigger zap"](https://zapier.com/zapbook/webhook/zapier/3977/buffer-zapier-from-webhook/)

The possible downside (depending on delivery time requirements) is that the delivery of onward webhooks would be complete "...within 5-15 minutes".  This doesn't quite fit my requirement, by may fit yours.

Edit:  A quick search on "fan-out" term also found [this on using Zapier Queue](https://zapier.com/support/questions/766/one-webhook-several-zaps/).  Again,as it's queuing I suspect there may be a delay in onward processing.

Edit2: Following email to Zapier support - situation is still as per links i.e.time delay, but "...in your zap you can define the length of the delay to minimize the lag. This case you shouldn't have any problem setting a 1 minute delay since there's no need for it to be any longer, which can help you get a lot closer to 'near real time'."

Edit3: Further info from Zapier support - apparently if you configure two Webhook-Webhook Zaps you can fire them both with one URL as "https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxhook1,xyhook2" - appears to fire both zaps pretty immediately.

Edit4: One thing to watch with the multi-zap approach (as Edit3) is that if one send to target fails then you can replay manually (via Zapier site and paying customer) - there's no ability (currently) to manage automatic retrying (not sure if there's any ability to monitor this event).

Comment: Good stuff.  Thank you for you answer.